# Cut string in words with ------- as delimiter

Tags: c++, find, substring

Hello i have the following sentence which is in a string and in one Line but very long:

```
l-s-s---s-l---s-s-s-------s-l---l---l-s-s-s-s-l---l-l-s-s---s---s-s---l-s-l-s---s-s-s-s---s---l-s-------l-s-l-l-s---s-l-l-s-l-s---l-s-l-l-s-l-------
```

(Its in Morse Code) The --- (3x-) seperates the letters and ------- (7x-) seperates the word.
How can i cut the very long code in words.

I've tried the following:

```cpp
    size_t posWordNext{};
    size_t posWordPre{};

    while (true) {
        posWordNext += code.find("-------");
        if (posWordNext >= code.size()) {
            break;
        }
        cout << code.substr(posWordPre, posWordNext) << endl;
        posWordPre = posWordNext;
    }
```

This is the output:

```
l-s-s---s-l---s-s-s
-------s-l---l---l-s-s-s-s-l---l-l-s-s
s-s-s-s-l---l-l-s-s---s---s-s---l-s-l-s---s-s-s-s---s---l
---s---s-s---l-s-l-s---s-s-s-s---s---l-s-------l-s-l-l-s---s-l-l-s-l-s---l-s
```

Comment: You tried it and what happened? There are often very good debugging hints in the output.

Comment: You never change `code`.  Do you expect `code.find("-------")` to return a different result in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: what should be an output? What should happen if input is incorrect (for example 6x`-`).

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)? There are some interesting overloads and defaulted parameters that you can play with.

Comment: This is the output:
l-s-s---s-l---s-s-s

-------s-l---l---l-s-s-s-s-l---l-l-s-s


s-s-s-s-l---l-l-s-s---s---s-s---l-s-l-s---s-s-s-s---s---l


---s---s-s---l-s-l-s---s-s-s-s---s---l-s-------l-s-l-l-s---s-l-l-s-l-s---l-s

but in comments it dont shows the newlines sorry

Comment: Please edit your post with the output from your program.  It's not useful in the comment.

Comment: You can start with something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/a1Eodac6x

Comment: @MarekR i want first to seperate the words then the letters and then convert them. is there a way with find and substring?

Comment: @DrewDormann i thought when i find the position of the delimiter (-------) I can cut with substring the word between the posWordPre which is the position of the last find and posWordNext which is in the position of current?

Comment: @Nexxizz step through your code in a debugger.  You will see that `std::string::substr` does not change the underlying string.  You will also see that the second parameter to `substr` is not a position, it is a length.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `code.find()`, you are searching from the beginning of the string again. You are not modifying `code` on each iteration, so `find()` will return the same offset each time. You should be passing `posWordPre` to the 2nd parameter of `find()` as a starting offset to begin searching from.

Also, when you are calling `code.substr()`, you are treating the 2nd parameter as an offset to stop at, but that parameter actually expects a character count instead of an offset.

Because of these mistakes, you are chopping up the `code` string at the wrong offsets.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
size_t posWordPre = 0, posWordNext;

while ((posWordNext = code.find("-------", posWordPre)) != string::npos) {
    cout << code.substr(posWordPre, posWordNext - posWordPre) << endl;
    posWordPre = posWordNext + 7;
}

if (posWordPre < code.size())
    cout << code.substr(posWordPre) << endl;
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/x7pW5p)

Comment: wow perfect solution thank you very much